# What is wrong with our menus?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

We have a wordpress blog: https://themerkle.com and the dropdown menus have had this bug ever since I can remember. If you hover quickly back and forth between the menus you will notice the artifact. The menu won't close and will remain open but appear blank white.

What is wrong with our menus? Is it the transition causing this? How could we fix it? I don't mind getting rid of the transition if that means getting rid of the artifact.

Comment: Your text is white in an inline style, `#secondary-navigation a{ color: #fffffff; }`  In your style.css sheet put `color: #000 !important;` on that item, I would guess it's a javascript error somewhere.

Comment: You should get rid of the timeout on your hover(in) callback.

Answer (score 1):

```
function mtsDropdownMenu() {
    var wWidth = $(window).width();
    if(wWidth > 865) {
        $('.navigation ul.sub-menu, .navigation ul.children').hide();
        $('.navigation li').hover( 
          function() {
            $(this).children('ul.sub-menu, ul.children').slideDown('fast');
          },
          function() {
          $(this).children('ul.sub-menu, ul.children').hide();
          }
        );
    } else {
        $('.navigation li').unbind('hover');
        $('.navigation li.active > ul.sub-menu, .navigation li.active > ul.children').show();
    }
}
```

You are using setTimeout and timer to clear the instances. This code is asynchronous. I believe this is causing the weird behaviour.
Rewrite like so sans the timer and delay. 
Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: Tried that and none of the menus would drop down on hover.

Answer (score 0):

You have white text on a white background.

See screenshot, as I said in the comments it's probably a JS setting in whatever drives your menu,  You can try overriding it with `!important`

[image]

And with that style switched off

[image]

Without knowing what theme you have and what options it has, and generally not having access to the files it will be a bit hard to tell exactly how to change that.  But over-ridding it might work, or maybe this will point you in the right path.

As a note, it's very easy to debug this using the browser debug menu, as you can see in the screenshots, typically f12 in most browsers.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the best solution out of all the answers. While it doesn't stop 2 menus opening up at once at least the previously open menu doesn't show up blank. Adding color #000 made the menu text black which made it hard to see so I changed it to that blue color you have in the screenshot. This would still need some additional investigation to see if I can get rid of the multiple open menus artifact.

Comment: It's probably an animation issue. I avoid using animation on dropdowns for this reason.  They probably call `.stop()` on the animation, this way it doesn't pile up from moving the mouse fast, and this keeps the menu open instead of closing it.  That's just a guess though.  I found using "fade" is safer then things like blind, or slide.

Comment: This is a theme I'm using so I didn't do the coding. The `.stop()` idea is probably correct. I guess the menu needs to be rewritten completely.

Answer (score 0):

You have a situation where opening the menu may occur after its expected closure, depending on how fast the mouse is moving.  Your method should remove the timeout, like this:

```
function mtsDropdownMenu() {
  var wWidth = $(window).width();
  if(wWidth > 865) {
      $('.navigation ul.sub-menu, .navigation ul.children').hide();
      var timer;
      var delay = 100;
      $('.navigation li').hover( 
        function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.children('ul.sub-menu, ul.children').slideDown('fast');
        },
        function() {
          $(this).children('ul.sub-menu, ul.children').hide();
        }
      );
  } else {
      $('.navigation li').unbind('hover');
      $('.navigation li.active > ul.sub-menu, .navigation li.active > ul.children').show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Same as the above, tried that and none of the menus would drop down on hover or click.